# Vue.js--vue cli3 changing favicon not working

Tags: vue.js, favicon

I wanted to change the default Vue favicon, so i changed the photo in the public folder to my own .ico image while still naming it as favicon. Except for this, i did no other changes, but it didn't work and still having the old default vue logo icon img, making no sense.
[image: img 1]
[image: my favicon img]

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Refresh After clearing the browser cash or local dev server a restart?

Comment: Favicons are heavily cached by the browser. Try using an incognito window to verify

Answer (score -1):

I generate a favicon from [here](https://www.favicon-generator.org/https://www.favicon-generator.org/) and I organize URL and favicon file like the following screenshot.

[image]

Generated favicon file work on all modern devices with cross-browser compatibility in my **Vue `ClI 3`** project.

Comment: No ! here are the details for the favicon supported file format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon